# Can't import .xml file larger than 20mb in my new Wordpress install

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

From what I've been reading there's a way editing the php.ini file (I know the Loaded Configuration File path, **but don't know how to edit it)**.

And there's also a way editing the .htaaccess file..

I have several Wordpress installs in my host. Each of them have a .htaccess file. I tried editing those files, but whenever I edit them, I get a **server error.**.

Moreover I've seen I could use a Splitter, but **couldn't find one for mac.**

So I'm lost here, and don't wanna be hours migrating the whole site when I know it only should take a couple of appropriate steps.

Comment: Whats .htaccess goto do with importing an XML? There could be lots of reasons why your breaking your htaccess, post what you have tried and we will tell you what you doing wrong. We not mind readers nor can we magically see your error messages.

Comment: Beacause apparently if u edit the code with `#set max upload file size
php_value upload_max_filesize xxM

#set max post size
php_value post_max_size xxM` some users seem to have expanded their size limits...

Comment: Why don't you split the file in 4 chunks? Keeping the XML headers and footer and splitting the `<items>`